# How do I validate an android.net.http.SslCertificate with an X509TrustManager?

Tags: android, security, android-webview, x509certificate

Android's `WebViewClient` calls `onReceivedSslError` when it encounters an untrusted cert. However, the `SslError` object I receive in that call doesn't have any way public way to get to the underlying `X509Certificate` to validate it against an existing `TrustStoreManager`. Looking at the source, I can access the `X509Certificate`'s encoded bytes thusly:

```
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler,
        SslError error) {
    Bundle bundle = SslCertificate.saveState(error.getCertificate());
    X509Certificate x509Certificate;
    byte[] bytes = bundle.getByteArray("x509-certificate");
    if (bytes == null) {
        x509Certificate = null;
    } else {
        try {
            CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            Certificate cert = certFactory.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
            x509Certificate = (X509Certificate) cert;
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            x509Certificate = null;
        }
    }

    // Now I have an X509Certificate I can pass to an X509TrustManager for validation.
}
```

Obviously, this is private API and is fragile, though I assume it is fairly reliable since they can't change the bundle format. Is there a better way?

Comment: Added a feature request: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62883&thanks=62883&ts=1385503421

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long wait it seems that a method called `getX509Certificate(): java.security.cert.X509Certificate` has been added to [`SslCertificate`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/net/http/SslCertificate.java) after my [feature request as issue 36984840](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36984840).