# Where should I save user-trusted Android X509Certificates?

Tags: android, security, truststore

My Android app needs to support connecting to untrusted servers over TLS. I handle this by installing a custom `SSLSocketFactory` with a custom `X509TrustManager` that shows a dialog asking the user to confirm the connection. I also handle this by overriding `WebViewClient`'s `onReceivedSslError` callback (which lead to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228800/how-do-i-validate-an-android-net-http-sslcertificate-with-an-x509trustmanager)).

These `X509Certificate`s are public keys only, so it doesn't matter if they're stored in cleartext. However, is there a place I can store them so that the system will automatically handle verification for me? Right now, I just put them in a `Set<String>` `SharedPreferences` and check any untrusted cert I receive against that `Set<String>`. Ideally, there would be a way to put them into the default truststore and then clear them from the default truststore when the user logs out.