# WebView and SSL certificates

Tags: android, ssl, android-webview

I have problems loading SSL secured web pages with Androids WebView. I always get errors like:
`onReceivedSslError: primary error: 3 certificate: Issued to: CN=intranet.<company>.de,C=DE,O=<company>,OU=<compay org unit>`

I already installed all the certificates of the certificate chain of this server into Android's keychain via Settings->Security->Install from SD card. I can even see that one of the installed certificates matches perfectly the error output from LogCat.
It gets even more strange if I use the default Browser app: it loads the page without any problems even if I uninstall all of the certificats mentioned before.
I don't really have any clue on how I can fix this without trusting all certificats by calling `handler.proceed()` in `onReceivedSslError()` which is a potential security issue.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Cheers
Bjoern

EDIT: The root certificate is self-signed because it's only intended to be used for intranet servers. I thought that all certificates I that I add to the Android trusted credentials would be trusted.

Comment: If you want us to help, you should provide real information rather than using someone else's site like `xyz.com` (that's a real site).

Comment: Sorry that I used a valid host. Unfortunately I cannot disclose information about the client and hope you can understand this.

Answer (score 2):

Well `onReceiveSslError()` and `handler.proceed()` should be used when connection to services with self signed certificates, the webview doesn't get along with them.

The think I would look right now is the server side ssl implementation. If you have multiple services with the same cert check for **SNI** support and if it´s well configured. Then look if the service you're connecting return the right certificate. Also check the Subject Alternative Name from your server and configure it under your needs.

For that task you can use those commands.

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect yourhost.com:443

openssl s_client -connect yourhost.com:443

openssl s_client -servername yourhost.com -connect yourhost.com:443

openssl s_client -connect yourhost.com:443 | openssl x509 -text
```

Here you have some more info from the Android documentation

> Common Problems with Hostname Verification As mentioned at the
>   beginning of this article, there are two key parts to verifying an SSL
>   connection. The first is to verify the certificate is from a trusted
>   source, which was the focus of the previous section. The focus of this
>   section is the second part: making sure the server you are talking to
>   presents the right certificate. When it doesn't, you'll typically see
>   an error like this:
>
> java.io.IOException: Hostname 'example.com' was not verified
>           at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.verifySecureSocketHostname(HttpConnection.java:223)
>           at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:446)
>           at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
>           at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
>           at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
>           at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
>           at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271)
>   One reason this can happen is due to a server configuration error. The
>   server is configured with a certificate that does not have a subject
>   or subject alternative name fields that match the server you are
>   trying to reach. It is possible to have one certificate be used with
>   many different servers. For example, looking at the google.com
>   certificate with openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 | openssl
>   x509 -text you can see that a subject that supports *.google.com but
>   also subject alternative names for *.youtube.com, *.android.com, and
>   others. The error occurs only when the server name you are connecting
>   to isn't listed by the certificate as acceptable.
>
> Unfortunately this can happen for another reason as well: virtual
>   hosting. When sharing a server for more than one hostname with HTTP,
>   the web server can tell from the HTTP/1.1 request which target
>   hostname the client is looking for. Unfortunately this is complicated
>   with HTTPS, because the server has to know which certificate to return
>   before it sees the HTTP request. To address this problem, newer
>   versions of SSL, specifically TLSv.1.0 and later, support Server Name
>   Indication (SNI), which allows the SSL client to specify the intended
>   hostname to the server so the proper certificate can be returned.
>
> Fortunately, HttpsURLConnection supports SNI since Android 2.3.
>   Unfortunately, Apache HTTP Client does not, which is one of the many
>   reasons we discourage its use. One workaround if you need to support
>   Android 2.2 (and older) or Apache HTTP Client is to set up an
>   alternative virtual host on a unique port so that it's unambiguous
>   which server certificate to return.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

## 2023

According to [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CustomTrust):

> By default, secure connections (using protocols like TLS and HTTPS) from all apps trust the pre-installed system CAs, and **apps targeting Android 6.0 (API level 23) and lower also trust the user-added CA store by default.** You can customize your app's connections using base-config (for app-wide customization) or domain-config (for per-domain customization).

**Meaning Android >6.0 and API >23 do NOT trust the user-added CA store by default.**

Instead, you must do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/debug_cas"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```

in `res/xml/network_security_config.xml`

where `@raw/debug_cas` is your self-signed or non-public CA certificate, in PEM or DER format.

[More details here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#TrustingDebugCa)

Answer (score 0):

It does seem to be the case in 2023 that the Android WebView still ignores user installed CA certificates when checking the validity of the certificate of a webpage. We will have to do it ourselves.

When you override `onReceivedSslError()`, you can get a list of the user installed CA certs on the device and check if any of them are able to attest to the validity of the certificate that is causing your ssl error.

```
override fun onReceivedSslError(view: WebView, handler: SslErrorHandler, error: SslError) {
   if(verifyAgainstUserInstalledCerts(getX509Certificate(error.certificate))){
        handler.proceed();
    }
}
```

First, we need to look at the `SslError` passed into `onReceivedSslError` and get its corresponding certificate. If you are targeting API level >=29, this is as simple as `error.certificate.x509Certificate`, but for lower API levels we need to do some additional finagling. I use this next function for that.

```
private fun getX509Certificate(sslCertificate: SslCertificate): Certificate? {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=29){
        return sslCertificate.x509Certificate
    }else{
        // credits to @Heath Borders at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228800/how-do-i-validate-an-android-net-http-sslcertificate-with-an-x509trustmanager
        val bundle: Bundle = SslCertificate.saveState(sslCertificate)
        val bytes: ByteArray? = bundle.getByteArray("x509-certificate")
        return if (bytes == null) {
            null
        } else {
            try {
                val certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
                certFactory.generateCertificate(ByteArrayInputStream(bytes))
            } catch (e: CertificateException) {
                null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now to actually test the error-throwing certificate against our user installed CA certs.

```
private fun verifyAgainstUserInstalledCerts(certificateInQuestion:Certificate?):Boolean {
    if(certificateInQuestion == null){return false}
    for (userInstalledCert in getUserInstalledCerts()) {
        try{
            certificateInQuestion.verify(userInstalledCert.publicKey)
            return true
        }catch(e:Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
            /* The x509Certificate's verify function throws an error when it fails to verify
             and never returns anything. We are forced to use try/catch to get the boolean
              value that we want, which is whether or not any certificate authority can attest
              to the validity of the given certificate */
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Ah, but there is another custom function that we are relying on. Let me define it here.

```
fun getUserInstalledCerts(): Collection<X509Certificate>{
        val results = mutableSetOf<X509Certificate>()
        try {
            val ks: KeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidCAStore")
            ks.load(null, null)
            val aliases = ks.aliases()
            while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
                val alias = aliases.nextElement() as String
                val cert = ks.getCertificate(alias) as X509Certificate
                if (alias.startsWith("user:")) {
                    results.add(cert)
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return results
    }
```