# Check in the onReceivedSslError() method of a WebViewClient if a certificate is signed from a specific self-signed CA

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, self-signed, webviewclient, ca

I would like to override the `onReceivedSslError()` of a `WebViewClient`. Here I want to check if the `error.getCertificate()` certificate is signed from a self-signed CA and, *only in this case*, call the `handler.proceed()`. In pseudo-code:

```
@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
    SslCertificate serverCertificate = error.getCertificate();

    if (/* signed from my self-signed CA */) {
        handler.proceed();
    }
    else {
        super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
    }
}
```

The public key of my CA is saved in a BouncyCastle resource called `rootca.bks`. How can I do?

Answer (score 27):

I think you can try as the following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        if (webView != null) {
            // Get cert from raw resource...
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            InputStream caInput = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.rootca); // stored at \app\src\main\res\raw
            final Certificate certificate = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
            caInput.close();

            String url = "https://www.yourserver.com";
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {                    
                @Override
                public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                    // Get cert from SslError
                    SslCertificate sslCertificate = error.getCertificate();
                    Certificate cert = getX509Certificate(sslCertificate);
                    if (cert != null && certificate != null){
                        try {
                            // Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/cert/Certificate.html#verify(java.security.PublicKey)
                            cert.verify(certificate.getPublicKey()); // Verify here...
                            handler.proceed();
                        } catch (CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException | NoSuchProviderException | SignatureException e) {
                            super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
                    }
                }
            });

            webView.loadUrl(url);
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// credits to @Heath Borders at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228800/how-do-i-validate-an-android-net-http-sslcertificate-with-an-x509trustmanager
private Certificate getX509Certificate(SslCertificate sslCertificate){
    Bundle bundle = SslCertificate.saveState(sslCertificate);
    byte[] bytes = bundle.getByteArray("x509-certificate");
    if (bytes == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        try {
            CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            return certFactory.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

If failed validation, logcat will have some information such as `java.security.SignatureException: Signature was not verified...`

If success, here's a screenshot:

[image: BNK's screenshot]

Comment: Yes!!! This solution actually works and looks secure to me - it verifies if the serer certificate is indeed signed with CA key (given CA public key). Thank you very much!!! :-)

Comment: what should I keep here --> R.raw.rootca ?

Comment: @jeet.chanchawat it´s cert file, for example ´rootca.crt´, you can find more info at https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#UnknownCa

Comment: @BNK I am stuck with the signature exception. I have changed the line cert.verify(cert.getPublicKey()); just to confirm. I am still getting same signature exception. please help.

Answer (score 7):

I think this should work (`SSL_IDMISMATCH` means "Hostname mismatch").

```
@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
    SslCertificate serverCertificate = error.getCertificate();

    if (error.hasError(SSL_UNTRUSTED)) {
        // Check if Cert-Domain equals the Uri-Domain
        String certDomain = serverCertificate.getIssuedTo().getCName();
        if(certDomain.equals(new URL(error.getUrl()).getHost())) {
          handler.proceed();
        }
    }
    else {
        super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
    }
}
```

If "hasError()" is not working, try `error.getPrimaryError() == SSL_IDMISMATCH`

Check [Documentation of SslError](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/SslError.html) for all error-types.

**EDIT:** I tested the function on my own self-cert server (its a Xampp), and I got Error #3.
That means you have to check for `error.hasError(SslError.SSL_UNTRUSTED)` for a self-signed cert.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not answer the original question. I don't want to check if the certificate authority is not trusted and in that case proceed (which will nullifies the use of SSL), but I want to check if the certificate is signed from a self-signed CA of which I know the public key.

Comment: You can add add a check:

`serverCertificate.getIssuedTo().getCName().equals(new URL(error.getUrl()).getHost())`

Answer (score 0):

based on documentation:

Have you tried using the method `getIssuedBy().getDName()` of  class SslCertificate. This method returns a String representing "The entity that issued this certificate".

Take a look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/SslCertificate.html#getIssuedBy()

Then you just need to know wich string is returned when it is self signed.

EDIT: I think that if it is selfsigned, that should return empty string, and if not, it would return the entity

Regards

Comment: That's not a good solution. Anyone can "fake" that name. Since we have the public key of the root CA, the correct solution is to check if the certificate is signed from it. And this brings us back to the original question...

Comment: good morning! just for self information, how could anyone set that?  there are no set methods for that value. Regards

Comment: anyway, if you change the way condition, it could fix your problem, just check if ...getDName equals your known certifier entity. Or maybe im not understandig your problem ok. Excuse me if that is the problem

Comment: Anyone can create a self-signed certificate, so anyone can create a certificate with a certain certifier entity. In short: your suggestion is not robust and nullifies the use of SSL.

Comment: Ok. Let us know how do you get it when achieved! Regards